# Is it possible to have real-time co-editing in Netbeans 7.1?

Tags: netbeans, real-time, edit

Is this possible?

Me and some mates in school need to collaborate in Netbeans.

Do anyone know if this is possible?

we are not on same computer.

Comment: I guess you're not talking about all sitting at the same computer? AFAIK Netbeans does not do this, and a quick search of their site for plugins didn't turn up anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that what you need is a [revision control server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control), so all of you can work on the same project, while documenting the changes that are made.

For this you just need an account to a  svn/cvs/(other) server.

[You may want to read the Netbeans functionalities for this use case here.](http://netbeans.org/features/ide/collaboration.html)

You can setup a project on [code.google.com](http://code.google.com) or [unfuddle.com](http://unfuddle.com), after each of the project members has a login credential you just configure your project in Netbeans:

1. Create a new project in netbeans;
2. In the Team menu select the kind of collaboration tool you will be using (svn for example, on code.google.com) and make your initial
   commit.
3. After this your mates only need to open their netbeans, go into team->svn->checkout and they'll get their own copy of the project.

Now all you need to do is code, and after you finish/alter an object, function, etc, you just "commit" this change to the server, which will be available to all others as soon as they "update" (It's not real-time, of course, but i don't see how it can be trully realtime, as you would never be able to execute your program/script, as others may have errors or uncompleted statements at any given moment).

Its also possible to rollback, in case a change creates problems, or to create issues and assign team members tasks (at least when using google code).

This is the way collaborative projects normally work.

Answer (score 1):

See: [NetBeans 6.8 Collaborative editing](NetBeans 6.8 Collaborative editing). It states:

> > It looks like the Developer collaboration module was discontinued after the release of NetBeans 6.5.... at least as a stand-alone feature.

I'd also recommend having a search for ["collaborative editing"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=collaborative+editing) as the question has been asked a number of times with slight variations.